# @Named annotation not working

Tags: jakarta-ee, annotations, cdi

I'm having some problems using the `@Named` annotation. For example the following bean works correctly, it receives and uploaded file:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void submit() throws IOException {
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();

    // Now you can save bytes in DB (and also content type?)

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage(String.format("File '%s' of type '%s' successfully uploaded!", fileName, contentType)));
}

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}
```

}

However if I replaces the `@ManagedBean` and `@RequestedScope` with `@Named` and `@RequestScoped` it fails with this exception:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'bean' resolved to null

I know `@Named` do I have an incorrect version set in my Netbeans project or something along those lines? I'm deploying on a Glassfish 4 server too.

Thanks

Comment: I think the other question should have been marked as 'duplicate'  since it was asked after the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a `beans.xml`, as needed by CDI 1.1?

Comment: ah no. I'll try that...

Comment: CDI 1.1 detects implicit beans by default. Ìf you have `@Named @RequestScoped`, then `beans.xml` should not be required for the bean to be discovered.

Comment: I have another problem now with CDI and tomahawk but I've started it as a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20719382/tommahawk-myfaces-and-cdi