# Tommahawk Myfaces and CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, myfaces

I'm having some problems using CDI with [Tommahawk Myfaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) when trying to create a JSF page to upload a file. Referring to this question it looks as though Tommahawk MyFaces isn't compatible with CDI but is this correct?

My Bean is like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean {
private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void submit() throws IOException {
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();

    // Now you can save bytes in DB (and also content type?)

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage(String.format("File '%s' of type '%s' successfully uploaded!", fileName, contentType)));
    }

    public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
        return uploadedFile;
    }

    public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
        this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
    }
}
```

But as soon as I replace `@ManagedBean` and `@RequestScoped` with `@Named` or `@Model` I get the following warning when deploying:

> WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.TomahawkFacesContextFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.

And when I upload a file with the following JSF page, the value of `UploadedFile` is null when I use `@Named` or `@Model`. but not with `@ManagedBean' and`@RequestScope`. This is the`.xhtml` file and I do use tommahawk Myfaces:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Tomahawk file upload demo</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <t:inputFileUpload value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" />
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit()}" />
            <h:messages />
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

So I assume CDI does not like the tomahawk library as there is no default constructor?

Comment: Try setting up Extensions Filter. You can find more information about it [Here](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/extensionsFilter.html)

Comment: Extensions filter is already set-up as it works with @ManagedBean. I just haven't shown the XML for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at '[Begginning Java EE 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143024626X)' it specifies that CDI 1.1 treats any class as a CDI bean which statifies (amongst other things) :

> It has a default constructor with no parameters with no parameters ,
>   or it declares a constructor annotated @Inject.

It looks as though [TomahawkFacesContextFactory](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/apidocs/org/apache/myfaces/webapp/filter/TomahawkFacesContextFactory.html) doesn't fulfil this requirement.

** EDIT **
The above seems to be [confirmed in the CDI specification here.](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#declaring_managed_bean) I've switched to PrimeFaces too and again this has similar problems with CDI however I not on their [announcement here](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2976) that:

> PrimeFaces 5.0 will ship with a new component model supported by annotation, and CDI compatible (or Spring or Guice!).

Comment: I see. Pretty weird, because CDI should't have to mess with any JSF artifacts, but theorically it is simple thing to fix. I have created [TOMAHAWK-1671](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMAHAWK-1671) to investigate further this topic.